How to use python regex to get the first occurrence of a substring
I have the following script trying to get the first occurrence of the word "symbol", but it keeps returning the last one (print "symbol in the middle and end"). How can I achieve that with re.search? I need to use re.search so that I can get the contents before and after the first "symbol".
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
regex = "[\s\S]*(symbol[\s\S]*)"
match = re.search(regex, test_string)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
    print(result)


Why do you have those [\s\S]* parts in your regex?

Why do you need a regexp if you're just searching for a fixed string? Just use if 'symbol' in test_string:

To answer your question, change the first * to *? to make it non-greedy.

Side-note: While it's not going to bite you in this particular case, always use raw strings for regex (if you had warnings turned up, you'd get one for that regex pattern, due to unrecognized string escape sequences). Develop the habit, and you won't get bitten later. It's just one more character: regex = r"[\s\S]*(symbol[\s\S]*)" (note little r before string literal). Otherwise, next time you need to seek for a word boundary with \b, you'll inadvertently be searching for an ASCII backspace.

@Barmar's suggestion of "change the first * to *?" solved my problem! Thanks!!

Your current pattern has multiple issues, one of which is that you should be using a lazy dot to find the first occurrence of symbol.
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
match = re.search(r'.*?\bsymbol (.*?)(?=(?: \bsymbol\b|$))', test_string)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
    print(result)  # but I want the first occurence of


While all the methods are relatively fast for small strings, the performance difference becomes more pronounced with larger strings or complex operations (regular expressions or manual looping). partition() remains one of the fastest, as it is optimized for splitting based on a delimiter.
Solution using partition():
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurrence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
before, word, after = test_string.partition("symbol")

print(f"Text before: {before}")
print(f"Text after: {after}")

Solution using re.search():
import re

test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurrence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"

regex = "(.*?)symbol(.*)"
match = re.search(regex, test_string)

if match:
    before = match.group(1)  # Text before the first "symbol"
    after = match.group(2)   # Text after the first "symbol"
    print(f"Before the first 'symbol': {before}")
    print(f"After the first 'symbol': {after}")
else:
    print("No match found.")

Solution using find():
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurrence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
index = test_string.find("symbol")

if index != -1:
    print(f"Text before: {test_string[:index]}")
    print(f"Text after: {test_string[index + len('symbol'):]}")

Solution using split():
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurrence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
before, after = test_string.split("symbol", 1)

print(f"Text before: {before}")
print(f"Text after: {after}")

Solution using index():
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurrence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
index = test_string.index("symbol")

before = test_string[:index]
after = test_string[index + len("symbol"):]

print(f"Text before: {before}")
print(f"Text after: {after}")


The problem is that [\s\S]* matches every character that is either a space (\s) or is not a space (\S). This is equivalent to "any character" (.). And it matches as many of those as possible (*), so the symbol will be as late possible.
Remove them.
test_string = "I have three symbol but I want the first occurence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end"
regex = "(symbol.*)"
match = re.search(regex, test_string)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
    print(result)
    # Prints:
    # symbol but I want the first occurence of symbol instead of the symbol in the middle and end


You don't need re.search for this. If you want the text before and after the first occurrence of "symbol", you can just use str.partition:
before, match, after = test_string.partition('symbol')

if match:
    do_whatever_with(before, after)

And if you were searching for something that actually needed a regex, the way to go would be
match = re.search(r'symbol', string)  # pretending this needs a regex

if match:
    before = string[:match.start()]
    after = string[match.end():]

rather than trying to use [\s\S]* to match what comes before and after.
